# select as sql and use in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

i want select from my sql and create a session from one table field

```
string strquery = "select * from Registration where username=@username ";
SqlConnection connection2 = DBConnection.getConnection();
connection2.Open();
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
cmd2.Connection = connection;
cmd2.CommandText = strquery;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@username", txt1_username.Text);

SqlDataReader nwReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
string cus = "";
if (nwReader.Read())
{
    cus = nwReader["customer_id"].ToString();
}
nwReader.Close();

connection.Close();
Session["customer_id_se"] = cus.ToString();
Response.Redirect("Wedding.aspx");
```

my problem is: i can't use that field and use in session

Comment: you are creating `connection2` and opening `connection`, then what is the need for `connection2` in this block?

Comment: Check SqlConnection object ... Are you playing with MySQL database through SqlConnection ?

Comment: @Sami : what make you to think so?

Comment: This sentence ..."i want select from my sql " 
Check does your Reader has value with if (nwReader.Read())

Comment: thanks sir connection changed to connection2 and now another error: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present from  cus = nwReader["customer_id"].ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing few mistakes, let me point them first(obviously it will solve the issue too).

1. As i mentioned in the comment,  "you are creating `connection2` and
   opening `connection` using  `connection.Open();` it should be either
   `connection2.Open();` or remove `connection2` from the block.
2. The [`.Parameters.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x(v=vs.110).aspx) method expect `SqlDbType` specify them and add its value using the following statement.

   ```
   cmd2.Parameters.Add("@username",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt1_username.Text;
   ```
3. There may be situations where `nwReader` will not having any rows(query returns no result). Accessing value from it in such situation will give you exception as `"Invalid attempt to read when no data is present"`, So you need to check for existence of data in the Reader before accessing it.

That is you should use like the following:

```
SqlDataReader nwReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
string customerId = String.Empty;
if (nwReader.HasRows)
{
    customerId = nwReader["customer_id"].ToString();
}
```

4. `customerId` is already a string so you need not to convert it again using `.ToString()` before assigning to the session.  So the complete scenario can be coded as like the following:

```
string strquery = "select * from Registration where username=@username";
SqlConnection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
connection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
cmd2.Connection = connection;
cmd2.CommandText = strquery;
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt1_username.Text;

SqlDataReader nwReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
string customerID = "";
if (nwReader.HasRows)
{
    customerID = nwReader["customer_id"].ToString();
}
nwReader.Close();
connection.Close();
Session["customer_id_se"] = customerID;
```

**Note :-**

> If `nwReader.HasRows` is false means there is no such record for the
>   specific username, in this case `customerID` and hence
>   `Session["customer_id_se"]` will be blank.

**Updates** as per **HansKesting's** comment,

`Select *` will fetch the entire rows which satisfies the condition in the Where clause. If you requires only a single value and you are sure that the result will be either empty or a single value then you can use `SELECT column_name from ...` and in such situations use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the value.

Comment: session is empty can't use in another page

Comment: @haik_khosrovian : which means means there is no such record for the specific username

Comment: A further tweak: if it's a single value you want, select *that* (instead of `*`) and use `ExecuteScalar` to get just that.

Comment: @HansKesting : yes absolutely. Let me include that too with the answer